# Change alignment of child in column in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I want to change the `horizontalAlignment` of particular child and remaining will use the same `horizontalAlignment`. Is this possible in `Column`?

For example, `Column` parent modifier use `horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,` and I want particular child modifier will be different `horizontalAlignment`.

```
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp)
                .fillMaxSize()
                .verticalScroll(rememberScrollState()),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            ScreenImage()
            Description()
            if (viewModel.isBluetoothEnabled) {
                ScanDeviceList(scanDeviceList)
            } else {
                Warning()
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
                TryAgainButtonView { tryAgainAction() }
                ButtonView { openSettingAction() }
            }
        }
```

I want to change `ScanDeviceList()` to be different `horizontalAlignment`

```
@Composable
fun ColumnScope.ScanDeviceList(scanDeviceList: List<ScanResult>) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
    AnimatedVisibility(scanDeviceList.isNotEmpty()) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.vailable_device),
        )
    }
}
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Modifier.align(Alignment.Start)` to align a particular child.
So for example to make your `ScanDeviceList()` at the Start of the column the code will be like this:

```
@Composable
fun ColumnScope.ScanDeviceList(scanDeviceList: List<ScanResult>) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
    AnimatedVisibility(
        scanDeviceList.isNotEmpty(),
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Start)
    ) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.vailable_device),
        )
    }
}
```

You can also pass the modifier as an argument to ScanDeviceList composable function to make it more generic to the code will be like this:

```
@Composable
fun ColumnScope.ScanDeviceList(
    scanDeviceList: List<ScanResult>, 
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
    AnimatedVisibility(
        scanDeviceList.isNotEmpty(), 
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Text(
            text = stringResource(R.string.vailable_device),
        )
    }
}
```

And when you call it you can specify the alignment that you want:

```
ScanDeviceList(scanDeviceList, modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Start))
```

**Note:** adding the modifier an argument to your composable functions is considered as a best practice because it will make the function reusable like the example above you can call ScanDeviceList with Alignment.Start or Alignment.End without changing the function itself, just by passing a different modifier as a parameter.

Comment: Another question, Suppose inside `ScanDeviceList()` have 2 `text` and I want to change 1st one is `Alignment.Start` and another one is `Alignment.Start`. So how can I use that one in that case? I am asking this you use `modifier` in `AnimatedVisibility`. Thanks

Comment: If the two texts are inside `AnimatedVisibility`, passing the modifier to `AnimatedVisibility` is enough, but if one or the two of them are direct child for the column pass the modifier to both of them, `Modifier.align(Alignment.Start))` needs to be applied to a direct child of the column, that's why I passed it to `AnimatedVisibility` in the example above not to `Text` because `AnimatedVisibility` is the direct child of the `Column`