# Change Alignment of particular child item in LazyColumn jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I am using `LazyColumn` in my `@Compsoable` screen. Inside `LazyColumn` there are so many child and which align `verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top` and   `horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally`. But in one child Item I want to use from `Start`. Can we do that?

```
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(16.dp),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {

            item {
                ommonContent()
            }

            item {
                HoldDescription()
            }

            item {
                WarningMessage()
            }

            item {
                Devices() // change this item from Start..
            }

            // more item in here
        }
```

**Expected Output**

[image]

I tried with these [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74556565/8266651) to `Modifier.align(Alignment.Start)` but it gives me error

```
@Composable
fun Devices(
    isEmpty: Boolean,
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        isEmpty,
        modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Start)
    ) {
        Text() 
    }
}
```

**Error in Image**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply the `align` modifier you can scope your composable with the required scope.
You can use:

```
@Composable
fun ColumnScope.Devices(
    isEmpty: Boolean,
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        isEmpty,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().align(Alignment.Start)
    ) {
        Text("xxx")
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can use:

```
@Composable
fun Devices(
    modifier: Modifier,
    isEmpty: Boolean,
) {
    AnimatedVisibility(
        isEmpty,
        modifier = modifier
    ) {
        Text("xxx")
    }
}
```

and then

```
item(){

   Column() {
        Devices(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().align(Alignment.Start),
            isEmpty = true)
    }
}
```